# Using NAudio, How do I get the amplitude and rhythm of an MP3 file?

Tags: naudio

The wife asked for a device to make the xmas lights 'rock' with the best of music. I am going to use an  Arduino micro-controller to control relays hooked up to the lights, sending down 6 signals from C# winforms to turn them off and on. I want to use NAduio to separate the amplitude and rhythm to send the six signals. For a specific range of hertz like an equalizer with six bars for the six signals, then the timing from the rhythm. I have seen the WPF demo, and the waveform seems like the answer. I want to know how to get those values real time while the song is playing.
I'm thinking ...
1. Create a simple mp3 player and load all my songs.
2. Start the songs playing.
3. Sample the current dynamics of the song and put that into an integer that I can send to which channel on the Arduino micro-controller via usb.

I'm not sure how to capture real time the current sound information and give integer values for that moment. I can read the e.MaxSampleValues[0] values real time while the song is playing, but I want to be able to distinguish what frequency range is active at that moment.

Any help or direction would be appreciated for this interesting project.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a fun signal processing project.

Using the `NAudio.Wave.WasapiLoopbackCapture` object you can get the audio data being produced from the sound card on the local computer.  This lets you skip the 'create an MP3 player' step, although at the cost of a slight delay between sound and lights.  To get better synchronization you can do the MP3 decoding and pre-calculate the beat patterns and output states during playback.  This will let you adjust the delay between sending the outputs and playing the audio block those outputs were generated from, getting near perfect synchronization between lights and music.

Once you have the samples, the next step is to use an FFT to find the frequency components.  Fortunately `NAudio` includes a class to help with this: `NAudio.Dsp.FastFourierTransform`.  (Thank you Mark!)  Take the output of the `FFT()` function and sum out the frequency ranges you want for each controlled light.

The next step is Beat Detection.  There's an interesting article on this [here](http://archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/programming/features/beatdetection/index.html).  The main difference is that instead of doing energy detection on a stream of sample blocks you'll be using the data from your spectral analysis stage to feed the beat detection algorithm.  Those ranges you summed become inputs into individual beat detection processors, giving you one output for each frequency range you defined.  You might want to add individual scaling/threshold factors for each frequency group, with some sort of on-screen controls to adjust these for best effect.

At the end of the process you will have a stream of sample blocks, each with a set of output flags.  Push the flags out to your Arduino and queue the samples to play, with a delay on either of those operations to achieve your synchronization.